# Does kubernetes cAdvisor include host machine (OS) metrics too when used with prometheus?

Tags: kubernetes

I am able to get metrics for kubernetes using prometheus (cAdvisor, nodes, pods, api-servers), but I want to get host maachine (OS) metrics too. So will that cAdvisor display those metrics or I have to use node-exporter separately for that matter?
Please help

Answer (score 1):

[cAdvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) can only provide metrics of containers.

Yes, you need to use [node-exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) for host metrics.